# Smoother touch swipe animation - jQuery or otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch, swipe

I have several dialogs on a web page.  The code does its job but is rather jumpy and glitch.  I suspect that the code is simply too heavyweight for an ipad.

```
    $(document).on("dialogopen", ".dialogClass", function() {
            console.log("dlg open");
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            //$(this).dialog("option", "width", $(window).width());
            //$(this).dialog("option", "height", $(window).height());
            $(this).dialog("option", "position", [0,0]);
            $(this).dialog("option", "draggable", "false");
            $(this).dialog("option", "width", $(window).width());
            $(this).dialog("option", "height", $(window).height());
            parent.css("width", $(window).width());
            parent.css("height",$(window).height());
            parent.css("position","fixed");
            parent.css("top","0px");
            parent.css('left','-' + $(window).width() + 'px');
            parent.animate({
                    left: 0
            }, speed, "easeOutBounce");
            $(this).swipe({
                    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                            if(distance >= 200){
                                    var dia = $(this);
                                    $(this).parent().animate({
                                            left : -$(window).width()
                                    },speed, "easeInExpo", function(e) {
                                            dia.dialog("close");
                                    });
                            }
                    }
             });


    });

    $(document).on("dialogclose", ".dialogClass", function() {
                    console.log("dlg close");
                    //$(this).dialog("destroy");
                    $(this).swipe("destroy");
                    $(this).swipe({
                            swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

                                    if(distance >= 150){
                                            var dia = $(this);
                                            $(this).parent().animate({
                                                    left : -$(window).width()
                                            },speed, "easeInExpo", function(e) {
                                                    dia.dialog("close");
                                            });
                                    }

                            }
                    });

    });
```

Is jQuery simply not the right tool for handling swipes?  I am using the following jQuery library:

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Have you tried Swipe?  http://swipejs.com/

Comment: Thanks.  That is a very nice slider but since it is a full on slider it will not work for my application.  I am working with jQuery UI dialogs.  I simply want to swipe them on\off the screen